# Opencart Multishop keep logged in

Tags: php, cross-domain, opencart, webshop

Today i found out that with a multishop in Opencart, it isn't possible to navigate from shop to shop without logging out.

This is because we change domain when going trough the shops.

Is there a way to keep the logged in status between different domains?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same Database for multiple sides and manage your login system and sessions over this same database.

Thats how i would do it on my self-coded sides ;)

Comment: I thought of the same thing.... But i don't wanna change the loggin features of Opencart.. It will take to much time to get this working.. Is it possible with Global variables ? So when I set them in opencart I can retrieve them from a other (multi)shop ?

Comment: I dont think so. Every webserver has its own gobal variables.